# Exponentially increasing amounts of time to repeat a function

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I've written my own math parser and for some reason it takes increasing amounts of time to parse when I tried to profile the parser.

For testing I used this input: `Cmd.NUM_9,Cmd.NUM_0,Cmd.NUM_0,Cmd.DIV,Cmd.NUM_2,Cmd.ADD,Cmd.NUM_6,Cmd.MULT,Cmd.NUM_3`

Single execution ~1.7ms
3000 repeats ~ 1,360ms
6000 repeats ~ 5,290ms
9000 repeats ~11,800ms

The profiler says 64% of the time was spent on this function:
 this is my function to allow implicit multiplications.

```
private void enableImplicitMultiplication(ArrayList<Cmd> input) {
    int input_size = input.size();
    if (input_size<2) return;
    for (int i=0; i<input_size; i++) {
        Cmd cmd = input.get(i);
        if (i>0) {
            Cmd last = input.get(i-1);
            // [EXPR1, EXPR2] => [EXPR1, MULT, EXPR2]
            boolean criteria1 = Cmd.exprnCmds.contains(cmd) && Cmd.exprnCmds.contains(last);
            // [CBRAC, OBRAC] => [CBRAC, MULT, OBRAC]
            // [NUM_X, OBRAC] => [NUM_X, MULT, OBRAC]
            boolean criteria2 = cmd==Cmd.OBRAC && (last==Cmd.CBRAC || Cmd.constantCmds.contains(last));
            // [CBRAC, NUM_X] => [CBRAC, MULT, NUM_X]
            boolean criteria3 = last==Cmd.CBRAC && Cmd.constantCmds.contains(cmd);
            if (criteria1 || criteria2 || criteria3) {
                input.add(i++, Cmd.MULT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on here??

I executed the repeats like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cmd[] iArray = {
        Cmd.NUM_9,Cmd.NUM_0,Cmd.NUM_0,Cmd.DIV,Cmd.NUM_2,Cmd.ADD,Cmd.NUM_6,Cmd.MULT,Cmd.NUM_3
    };
    ArrayList<Cmd> inputArray = new ArrayList<Cmd>(Arrays.asList(iArray));
    DirtyExpressionParser parser = null;
    int repeat=9000;
    double starttime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=0; i<repeat; i++) {
         parser = new DirtyExpressionParser(inputArray);
    }
    double endtime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("Duration: %.2f ms%n",(endtime-starttime)/1000000);
    System.out.println(parser.getResult());
}
```

Constructor looks like this:

```
public DirtyExpressionParser(ArrayList<Cmd> inputArray) {
    enableImplicitMultiplication(inputArray); //executed once for each repeat
    splitOnBrackets(inputArray); //resolves inputArray into Expr objects for each bracket-group
    for (Expr expr:exprArray) {
        mergeAndSolve(expr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the profiler indicate which line of code was taking the most time?

Comment: I think the problem here is the invokations of contains

Comment: No - I used NetBeans IDE to profile, it just gave me a list of functions and their cumulative execution times

Comment: Can you put  if (i>0)  near input.add() ? This may make execution time nearly equal for all situations.

Comment: @TI I am used an enum, Cmd is the enum

Comment: Is `contains(..)` recursive? If so it may open up a whole tree of calls most of which recompute the same results over and over again. This would lead to exponential runtime

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you mean that its the 3 conditionals which make it take long, but then how would I improve the time on that??

Comment: Each true condition add something to the list and after that, each true condition checks 1-element larger  list. Keeps getting larger and larger. avidD is right. Nwmwhat i said.

Comment: After 20000 iterations, it will start checking a list of 10s of thousands of things. After a million iterations, it will check a list of 1000000-element input. So this is O(N*N) (worst condition) algorithm, making exponential exec time. Maybe you can just add them altogether and check only once at the end, removing unnecessary if possible.

Comment: @avidD `contains` loops through until it finds the element I think

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't get that because the input_size is the same for each repeat (9 elements in the example above) ??

Comment: @user1094607 What about cmd?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I added the constructor in my post so you can see that the input_size does not change for each repeat. Cmd is just an enum with objects for each input 0,1,2...9 and +-/*

Comment: input.add(i++, Cmd.MULT); does not increase size of input ?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik it does but the `i++` increments to skip the added element. Besides that wouldn't explain why the first 3000 repeats is faster than the next 3000. All of these variables are local to each DEP object - so the next repeat shouldn't affect it

Comment: @user1094607 Cmd.exprnCmds.contains(cmd) checks for all already added elements of type exprnCmds ?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik it's a weird setup. The exprnCmds is a pre-compiled array of `Cmd.EXPR1, Cmd.EXPR2, ..., Cmd.EXPR30` allowing up to 30 sub-expressions in one input. When parsing, the original expression is reduced and input is replaced with a placement holder for a subexpression e.g. `1+2/3` first becomes `1+EXPR1` then `EXPR2`, where EXPR1=`0.666`, EXPR2=`1.666`. The Cmd is used as a placeholder, but being an enum doesn't hold the value. The values are held in a `HashMap<String,Double> variables` which keeps the name `EXPR1` and value `0.666`

Comment: When you say 64% of the time, is that self time or does it include callees? Self time is almost useless. Regardless, just interrupt it a few times, and you'll see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but the solution was to put the inputArray ArrayList creation inside the DEP() invocation. In that 11000ms it now did 1mil repeats. @Mike try the NetBeans 6.9.1 profiler if you have NetBeans I think it's pretty good. Self time is listed separately, so it is not included in the method invocation I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  microbenchmark code is altogether wrong: microbenchmarking on the JVM is a craft in its own right and is best left to dedicated tools such as jmh or Google Caliper. You don't warm up the code, don't control for GC pauses, and so on.

One detail which does come out by analyzing your code is this:

1. you reuse the same `ArrayList` for all repetitions of the function call;
2. each function call may insert an element to the list;
3. insertion is a heavyweight operation on `ArrayList`: the whole contents of the list after the inserted element must be copied.

You should at least create a fresh `ArrayList` for each invocation, but that will not make your whole methodology correct.

From our discussion in the comments I diagnose the following issue you may have with understanding your code:

In Java there is no such thing as a variable whose value is an object. The value of the variable is a *reference* to the object. Therefore when you say `new DirtyExpressionParser(inputArray)`, the constructor does not receive its own private copy of the list, but rather a *reference* to the one and only `ArrayList` you have instantiated in your `main` method. The next constructor call gets this same list, but now modified by the earlier invocation. This is why your list is growing all the time.

Comment: +1 Although it does seem the list grows with the number of iterations, making the algo O(something greater than N, maybe N^2).

Comment: Although the NetBeans memory profiler did say 0.2% time spent in GC? Actually it was like 5% at peak

Comment: @assylias Yes, I've aded some text covering that `add` operation. It's actually *insertion*, which makes it quite a bit worse than just increasing the size of input.

Comment: Thanks for the updates but I'm only self-taught from online-tuts so I wouldn't know what's wrong with this: `1.you reuse the same ArrayList for all repetitions of the function call;`, if you could share some links or elaborate that would be helpful?

Comment: You create a single `ArrayList` in your `main` method and pass *a reference to it* to the `DirtyExpressionParser` constructor in each repetition. Therefore this single `ArrayList` is being modified by the called code and then the modified version is being passed in the next repetition.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik aha! Now I get it. You hit the nail on the head, and the 9000 repeats took ~140ms now lol.

Comment: So it's 1.7 ms for a single execution vs. 140 for 9000 repeats---100 times less than expected from a linear extrapolation. This is a clear effect of non-warmed-up code.